# GCP Spanner: Secondary Index doesn't work in Update and Delete statements

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

Secondary Index doesn't work in Update and Delete statements in spanner. Due to which sometimes simple update and delete statements take a lot of time

I tried this: 
"update table1@{FORCE_INDEX=i_index1} set column1='abc' where column2='xyz'"

If this doesn't work then what is the alternate to make update and delete statements fast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the time, Cloud Spanner will automatically choose indexes that would make a query most efficient and there would be no need to specify any. In some cases, an index could choose an index that would make a query slower; which could be a possible explanation as to why your statements are running for a long time.

It is possible to [troubleshoot slow queries](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/troubleshooting-performance-regressions#review-schema) by looking at their secondary indexes. If you do find out that an index is slowing down your query, then you can [specify another index](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/secondary-indexes#index-directive).

As far as your Cloud Spanner goes, [secondary indexes are used for common queries](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/sql-best-practices#secondary-indexes), so only SELECT statements, to speed them up; indicating that UPDATE and DELETE statements will not include a secondary index.

Since you can only use your secondary index in a SELECT statement, I suggest that you try the following: 
   UPDATE table1
      SET column1 = ’abc’
    WHERE columnX IN
       (SELECT columnX
          FROM table1@{FORCE_INDEX = i_index1}
         WHERE column2 = ’xyz’)

You basically retrieve column values and set them as you WHERE condition values to match, using the secondary index as an intermediary. You might need to change the statement a bit if you want to match many columns.

Comment: Thanks for sharing details. I tried the approach that you mentioned but update is still very slow (though select is better with secondary index). 

PDATE table1 SET column1 = ’abc’ WHERE primarykeycolumn IN (SELECT primarykeycolumn FROM table1@{FORCE_INDEX = i_index1} WHERE column2 = ’xyz’)

I also tried it in partitioned-dml on console but no luck either.

gcloud spanner databases execute-sql abc --instance=xyz --enable-partitioned-dml --sql='update ******'

Any other suggestions!

Comment: I have tried the statement I have suggested to you and it works properly, but is slow as you have mentioned. Being curious, I also tried the original statement you provided and it did not work, which is intended as secondary indexes cannot be used directly in UPDATE or DELETE statements.

However, it seems like it is normal that Cloud Spanner takes a long time to run statements. The only thing you could do is either wait for the statement to finish, or restructure your database so that it runs statements as efficiently as possible. Using partitioned DML was already a good start.

Comment: You can look up [Cloud Spanner Best Practices](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/best-practice-list), which includes articles about Bulk Loading Best Practices, DML Best Practices, Schema Design Best Practices and SQL Best Practices, which will help you optimize your database.